# $\int _{\mathbb{T}^n}f(t)g(x-t)d\lambda (t)\in\mathbb{C}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{T}^n$ and $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{T}^n)$?

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, convolution, haar-measure

According to the book "Classical Fourier Analysis" (written by Loukas Grafakos) every locally compact group has a Haar measure. Consider the set $\mathbb{T}^n:=\mathbb{R}^n/(2\pi\mathbb{Z}^n)=\big\{x+2\pi\mathbb{Z}^n:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\big\}$ with the metric defined by $d(x+2\pi\mathbb{Z}^n,y+2\pi\mathbb{Z}^n):=\inf \big\{\Vert x-y+2\pi j\Vert _n:j\in\mathbb{Z}^n\big\}$. Then $\mathbb{T}^n$ is a locally compact group with respect to that metric. Therefore $\mathbb{T}^n$ has a Haar measure.

Suppose that $\lambda$ is the Haar measure of $\mathbb{T}^n$ such that $\lambda (\mathbb{T}^n)=1$.

**My question is:** $\int _{\mathbb{T}^n}f(t)g(x-t)d\lambda (t)\in\mathbb{C}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{T}^n$ and $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{T}^n)$? That is, is the convolution product of $f$ and $g$ well-defined for all $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{T}^n)$?

Unfortunately I have made no progress in trying to answer the above question.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Yes, and $\|f*g\|_1 \leq \|f\|_1\|g||_1$. This  a  simple and standard application of Fubini's Theorem. But the convolution may not be defined at every point. (It is define a.e.)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I already knew that the convolution was well defined for a.e.. My question is whether the convolution is defined **for all** $x\in\mathbb{T}^n$ since $\mathbb{T}^n$ is a compact group and $\lambda$ is a probability measure.

Comment: Just a note: That is an LCA group, but I unless I'm confused, it's not an $\mathbb{R}$ vector space. So I also don't know in what sense that would be a norm either. (I have a feeling that someone's going to point out to me that I've done a brain fart here, but I don't see how right now.)

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Define the sum in $\mathbb{T}^n$ by $(x+2\pi \mathbb{Z}^n)\oplus(y+2\pi \mathbb{Z}^n)=x+y+2\pi \mathbb{Z}^n$ and the scalar product by $\alpha \odot (x+2\pi \mathbb{Z}^n)=\alpha x+2\pi \mathbb{Z}^n$. Then $(\mathbb{T}^n,\oplus,\odot)$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-vetor space. To prove that $\Vert\cdot\Vert $ is indeed a norm note that $\mathbb{Z}^d$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to the standard topology.

Comment: Take $v = (k,0, 0, ...) \in \mathbb{T}^n$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $v  = 1\cdot v = (2\pi/2\pi) \cdot = (1/2\pi) \cdot (2\pi k, 0, 0, ...) = (1/2\pi) \cdot \textbf{0} = \textbf 0$. Also, I've never seen an $\mathbb R$ vector space that is compact before (except the trivial one of dimension zero).

Comment: I'll be honest -- I can't yet reduce this to a contradiction, but I'm still pretty sure this isn't an $\mathbb R$ vector space.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I think you're right! But that "norm" can be used to define a metric in $\mathbb{T}^n$.

Comment: Can you identify which axiom of a vector space is not satisfied by $(\mathbb{T}^n,\oplus,\odot)$? Using your observation we can conclude, for instance, that $(1,0)\in 2\pi \mathbb{Z}^2$ which is an absurd. However I can't show which vector space's axiom is not satisfied by $(\mathbb{T}^n,\oplus,\odot)$ since $\oplus$ and $\odot$ are apparently well-defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113732/discussion-between-jonathanz-supports-monicac-and-rfloc).

Comment: For anyone who comes on this question later, the results from the chat room is that the example for $(k,0,0,...)$ above leads to showing that the $\odot$ defined above fails the "Compatibility of scalar multiplication with field multiplication" axiom for a vector space, i.e. $(ab)\odot v = a \odot (b \odot v)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be any function in $L^{1}$ which is not in $L^{2}$. Take $g(y)=f(-y)$ so that $g$ is also in $L^{1}$. Then then convolution does not exist at $x=0$.